# php oop switch case does not work

Tags: php, oop, switch-statement, case

My switch case redirect every user to the first case, what is wrong?
i want that 'President' will redirect to admin.php

```
<?php require "header.php"; ?>
<?php
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['email']) ) {
$msg = urlencode('U dient ingelogd te zijn om op deze pagina te kunnen komen.');
header('location: login.php?msg=' . $msg);
die();
}

$role = $_SESSION['jobTitle'];
switch($role) {
case 'Finance' AND 'VP Finance':
    header('location: finance.php');
    break;
case 'VP Sales' AND 'Sales Manager (NA)' AND 'Sales Rep':
    header('location: sales.php');
    break;
case 'President':
    header('location: admin.php');
    break;
default:
    session_destroy();
    header('location: login.php');
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my database
http://i57.tinypic.com/2em21aw.png

Comment: try to remove AND condition after CASE 'Finance'

Comment: case 'Finance''VP Finance':
header('location: finance.php');
break;

Do you mean this? is does not work

Comment: write only case 'Finance'

Comment: where did you learn that `AND` switch case usage anyway? are they defined as `&&` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think that you meant OR instead of AND.
2. You are trying to compare result of AND with $role variable. Result of AND is always true.

You could rewrite

```
switch($role) {
    case 'Finance':
    case 'VP Finance':
        header('location: finance.php');
        break;
    case 'VP Sales':
    case 'Sales Manager (NA)':
    case 'Sales Rep':
        header('location: sales.php');
        break;
    case 'President':
        header('location: admin.php');
        break;
    default:
        session_destroy();
        header('location: login.php');
    }
```

Or you could write something more complicated with expression inside case.

```
switch(true) {
case ($role == 'Finance' OR $role == 'VP Finance'):
    header('location: finance.php');
    break;
case ($role =='VP Sales' OR $role =='Sales Manager (NA)' OR $role =='Sales Rep'):
    header('location: sales.php');
    break;
case $role == 'President':
    header('location: admin.php');
    break;
default:
    session_destroy();
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: He doesn't mean OR... And your answer provides and AND-solution... Your statement doesn't match your code...

Comment: @RichardBernards , are you sure?

Comment: Yes... Someone typing AND usually means AND... And the updated answer is indeed an example for using OR.

Comment: @RichardBernards , sorry, but variable cannot be equal to two values at the same time. It could be equal to the first value or! to the second value.

Comment: @RichardBernards If you look at the intent of the code in the question you see that he wants to run the first case for Finance and VP Finance roles. This means role needs to be tested for Finance OR VP Finance. As sectus pointed out, doing a boolean AND test where the same variable is on both the left and the right side does not make any sense, it will never match.

Answer (score 2):

AND statements cannot be used in switch cases... Try the following to achieve the same:

```
switch($role) {
    case 'Finance':
    case 'VP Finance':
        header('location: finance.php');
        break;
    case 'VP Sales':
    case 'Sales Manager (NA)':
    case 'Sales Rep':
        header('location: sales.php');
        break;
    case 'President':
        header('location: admin.php');
        break;
    default:
        session_destroy();
        header('location: login.php');
}
```